# Incorrect value is returned when retrieving value from a Store

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a component that displays a set of buttons:

[Step navigator component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86cU.png)

For every click in a button I want to display a different view and set the current view in a "step"-variable. Since I wan't to access this variable from different components in my application I'm storing this "step"-variable in a store.

I'm retrieving the value from a data-attribute from which I set when I render the list:

**StepNavigator.svelte**

```
<script>
  import { step } from "../stores/step.js";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import Icon from "./Icon.svelte";

  function setStep(e) {
    step.update(n => e.target.tabIndex);
  }

  let stepItems = [
    {
      title: "Option 1",
      selections: []
    },
    {
      title: "Option 2",
      selections: ["One selection"]
    },
    {
      title: "Option 3",
      selections: []
    },
    {
      title: "Option 4",
      selections: ["Selection 1", "Selection 2"]
    },
    {
      title: "Option 5",
      selections: []
    },
    {
      title: "Option 6",
      selections: []
    }
  ];
</script>
<section class="step-navigator">
  <h2>Configure product item 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ispum dolor samet dolor ipsum lorem samet.</p>
  <ul>
    {#each stepItems as stepItem, index}
      <li>
        <button class={$step === index ? 'active' : 'inactive'} on:click={setStep} tabindex={index}>
          <div>
            <h3>{stepItem.title}</h3>
            <div class="selected-items">
              {#if stepItem.selections.length > 0}
                {#each stepItem.selections as selection, index}
                  {#if index !== 0}, {selection}{:else}{selection}{/if}
                {/each}
              {:else}Nothing selected{/if}
            </div>
          </div>
          <Icon iconType="ok" iconColor={stepItem.selections.length > 0 ? 'var(--theme-color--success)' : '#999'} strokeWidth="4" />
        </button>
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
  <div class="price-container">
    <div class="price">7560 USD</div>
    <div class="price-information">Disclaimer text goes here</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Step.js**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const step = writable(0);
```

The thing is that I randomly get value "-1" when clicking my buttons:

[GIF showing the error when clicking the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zREG8.gif)

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: step.update(n => e.target.tabIndex); n???? or first debug your setStep function

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could elaborate your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree it's weird that your tab indexes are coming back as `-1`, even though you seem to be setting them correctly.

But instead of using the `tabIndex` in `setStep`, I might just pass the index in  directly, like so:

```
function setStep(index) {
  step.update(n => index);
}
```

```html
<button class={$step === index ? 'active' : 'inactive'} on:click={() => setStep(index)} tabindex={index}>
```

Here's a Svelte REPL for that: https://svelte.dev/repl/b70ed5be24074cf48c3d3e6a375c327e?version=3.12.1

---

Side note, but also if you're not using that `n` variable, then it could be slightly cleaner to use `set` instead of `update`:

```
function setStep(index) {
  step.set(index);
}
```